# Pi-Hole on Raspberry Pi 3 displays WRONG time

Tags: timekeeping

Excuse me Please:

I am finding Pi-Hole to be displaying traffic events 5 hours into the future.
i.e. current time: 1100, Pi-Hole Graph time: 1600.
Raspberry Pi screen displays correct time for EST that I live in.
As I have gone through every screen of the Pi-Hole web UI and found NOTHING regarding time, what am I doing wrong that has this device so confused?
Note: I am by no means a Linux expert, only peripherally familiar.
Thank you for the thoughtful time taken to reply.
CAH

Comment: It must be UTC time which is 5 hours ahead.

Comment: Fix it with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

Answer (score 1):

Enter `timedatectl status`. That should show your set time zone, which I assume UTC now.
To change it enter `tzselect`, choose Americas>United States>your region and follow confirming.

Comment: This is only a temporary solution which lasts only until you log out. You need to set your timezone as suggested by @Dougie above to make it permanent.